# Push to javascript object provides wrong result

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I'm trying to create a sortable javascript object, but when I push to the object instead of creating a new object it creates 2 of the first objects.

I have created a jsFiddle to better display what is going on at https://jsfiddle.net/chasiv/9ee2cxvu/

The expected result would be the last console.log would result in:
joomUser:[{"id":"895","name":"User # 2"}, {"id":"894","name":"Administrator"}]

I then need to sort this on name, so I believe the following would accomplish this, but please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
joomUser.sort( function(a,b) { return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) });
```

Comment: Put your   var access = {}; inside the loop

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve from a highler level, but I'm certain you're trying it in a badly structured, very suboptimal way.

Comment: Thanks Observer, that was stupid simple :-)   I've updated the fiddle with the corrections and the sort and it worked fine.